# How to remove chapter # and title from headings

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I am using this code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrule{\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}
\setlength{\headheight}{24.7pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    text of first chapter
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    text of second chapter
\end{document}
```

I'd like to remove the text CHAPTER 1. FIRST CHAPTER that appears in the second page ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added `\fancyhead{}` (and `\lipsum` to test even/odd pages).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand\headrule{\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}
\setlength{\headheight}{24.7pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    text of first chapter\lipsum[1-30]
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    text of second chapter
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, the original header was

[image]